# Running a MySQL Insert when update fails

Tags: mysql, insert-update

What is the fastest approach to update a row and if the parameters don't exist insert it.

My table has 2 columns for ids `quote_id, order_id` and those columns combined would make a unique column. I don't want 2 rows containing the same `quote_id` and `order_id` but either can have multiple rows.

```
id | quote_id | order_id
1  | q200     | o100
2  | q200     | o101
3  | q201     | o100
```

Previously I would have added a third field and combined those 2 fields with a `-` so I could use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. But this is not very efficient as I seem to forget to add those fields sometimes.

My idea is to try to run the update query and if it fails the insert it as I run a lot more update queries then insert. How would I put this into a single query instead of the MySQL server having to return a error and then I rerun the insert query.

`if (
   UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2 WHERE some_column=some_value === ERROR
) THEN 
   INSERT INTO table_name ....`

I looked through some of the MySQL documentation and I couldn't find a example that showed how an error is detected in a `IF` statement

Comment: If those fields represent the logical key for that table, why can't you make them the primary key and use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: Did you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @David Neither of those fields is unique on its own but together they are. Is there a way to make a combined column primary key? Also in case your wondering the id column is strictly a primary key in the database and is not sent to the clients. So when updating the values I don't have that value present in the data.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes I read most of that page before and from what I gather this wont work for me as the fields are not unique.

Comment: Yes, you can make a compound primary key like `PRIMARY KEY(quote_id, order_id)`.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks. If you put this in a answer I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE constraint over the column(s) that identify rows uniquely. It's normal to use multiple columns for this, and SQL support syntax for it:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  quote_id VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  order_id VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  other_data VARCHAR(4),
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY(quote_id, order_id)
);
```

Then you can rely on the unique constraint to cause an INSERT to fail and run an UPDATE instead:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (quote_id, order_id, other_data) VALUES ('q200', 'o100', 'blah blah')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  other_data = VALUES(other_data);
```

Using the VALUES() clause in the UPDATE part means "use the same value for the respective column that I tried to use in the INSERT part."